# Aptana Studio 3.0.4 Unable to find a Ruby executable with RVM

Tags: ruby, rvm, aptana

I just downloaded Aptana Studio 3.0.4 on Ubuntu 11.04 32 bits. I've been using RVM for Ruby and Rails development. I imported a rails project into Aptana and tried to run it. But when I do, I get the error from the title:
Unable to find a ruby executable.

When I open the Terminal view, it doesn't find ruby with ruby -v either. I think it's correctly configured on my system with the .bash_profile file. But when I open the Terminal view and use "rvm use 1.9.2", and try ruby -v (which does work), Aptana still doesn't find it.

Do you know if there's a way to tell Aptana to use RVM or configure the path to Ruby somewhere?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we're unable to find ruby inside our Terminal view, it means that somehow the path isn't set up properly. It sounds like it does find it after you run "rvm use 1.9.2", which would lead me to think that rvm is set up, but there's no default ruby set. Try running "rvm use 1.9.2 --default", restart Studio and then try "ruby -v" in the Terminal view.

Comment: This did it, telling rvm to use 1.9.2 by default. Thank you very much! It's awesome to have the lead developer of the product on the S.O. community, it's comforting. Now if I can manage to debug my Rails app, the search for my Ruby IDE will be over with Aptana :)

Comment: Docs for the ruby debbugger are here: http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Ruby+Debugger

Basically, make sure you install the 'ruby-debug-ide19' gem for Ruby 1.9. Then to debug your rails app, right click it in the Project Explorer and choose 'Debug Server'.

Comment: Thanks again Christopher! I'm following up on this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676249/how-do-i-debug-a-rails-application-in-aptana-studio-3.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the path to make it work.

Windows Start Menu -> Computer -> Properties (in the context menu) -> Settings -> Advanced -> Environment variables -> PATH

Add the path of your ruby executable.

I had the same problem, and I just solved it this way.