# How do I debug a Rails application in Aptana Studio 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, aptana

Does Aptana Studio include debugging for Rails apps just as RubyMine does with breakpoints and everything? I'm using Aptana Studio 3.0.5 and haven't been able to find how to get this working.

Comment: I have followed the steps mentioned in my blog to run rails application in debug using aptana studio http://cyalla.blogspot.in/2012/08/running-ruby-on-rails-application-in.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Aptana Studio 3+ does have Ruby debugging. Other than breakpoints in HAML files misbehaving somewhat, I've been able to use this without any problems.

However, you must make certain that you have installed the gem `ruby-debug-ide` (you can install it with the command: `gem install ruby-debug-ide`).

To verify that the appropriate debug gems are installed, run `gem list` in your Terminal application of choice (not sure what platform you are on) and be sure it's there ... look for these lines in the output:

> ruby-debug-base19 (0.11.25) 
>   ruby-debug-ide (0.4.16)

Hope that helps!

Comment: I see these gems with gem list:
ruby-debug-base19 (0.11.25)
ruby-debug-base19x (0.11.30.pre2)
ruby-debug-ide (0.4.17.beta8, 0.4.16)
ruby-debug19 (0.11.6)
How should I proceed? I find the option to debug a single Ruby file, but not a Rails application.

Comment: In Aptana, what output do you see in the Console view when you attempt to start the debug server? And, just to clarify, how do you start the debug server (i.e., what 'buttons' do you use to fire it up)?

Comment: How should I start the debug server? I was looking at the Run menu > Debug As... and I get "ruby application". But this tries to debug the current open rb file. I also tried on the App Explorer to run Commands > Debug Server and get an exception: http://pastebin.com/ZLQz2RW7

Comment: I must add I'm debugging the same code correctly with RubyMine, but I feel more comfortable with the Eclipse environment so I'm looking to switch to Aptana for Rails development.

Comment: Fernando, it looks like the debugger cannot find your columnizer gem. ("Could not find columnize (>= 0.3.1)"). When you run gem list, do you see that in there? I just made the switch to RVM (from MacPorts) and had to reinstall a ton of gems!

Comment: With gem list I can see it's there: columnize (0.3.4 ruby). I even reinstalled it and restarted Aptana but it still shows the same message.

Comment: Quick question going back to the gems in your first comment, which versions are active? I ask because I have ruby-debug-base19(0.11.25) and ruby-debug-ide(0.4.16) and was wondering if the newer versions were, perhaps, causing an issue if they were active. Otherwise, we're both running similar setups (I have Ruby 1.9.2 p290 as well).

Comment: Also, found this discussion on Aptana's tender app site. Might be helpful even if it is Windows focused. 

https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/2896-issues-with-aptana-30-radrails/page/1?to=%2Fdiscussions%2Fproblems%2F2896-issues-with-aptana-30-radrails%2Fpage%2F2%3Fto%3D%252Fdiscussions%252Fproblems%252F2896-issues-with-aptana-30-radrails%252Fpage%252F1

Comment: The link didn't help, I'm still getting the same error. Should I add columnizer gem to the project's gemfile? I don't know...

Comment: Ok, finally got it working, gem list: ruby-debug-base19 (0.11.25)
ruby-debug-ide19 (0.4.12)
ruby-debug19 (0.11.6). Just have to make sure the path is set correctly and the debugging gems have been installing. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It seems that ruby-debugbase19 hasn't been updated since 2011