# How to debuge ruby on rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to debug by ruby on rails application but I don't know the steps for debugging ruby on rails application using aptana studio 3.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. What happened when you typed "rails debugger" into google and tried some of the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to search before you ask a question

here are something useful:

http://cyalla.blogspot.in/2012/08/running-ruby-on-rails-application-in.html

https://github.com/SketchUp/sketchup-ruby-debugger/wiki/How-to-set-up-an-IDE-for-debugging-Ruby-extensions-in-SketchUp

[How do I debug a Rails application in Aptana Studio 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676249/how-do-i-debug-a-rails-application-in-aptana-studio-3)